# PROC-SQL - Return only the row with the minimum date value

Tags: sql, group-by, proc-sql

I have tried following some guides on here for this but I think the issue might lie in the format of my date fields.

I have a table that looks like :

```
ID    Creation_Date       Action_date
1     01JAN19:00:06:33    01JAN19:09:00:00  
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    04JAN19:09:00:00
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    05JAN19:09:00:00
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    06JAN19:09:00:00
3     21JAN19:09:17:01    22JAN19:09:00:00
3     21JAN19:09:17:01    23JAN19:09:00:00
```

I want to return all the unique ID's and only the most recent Action_Date, to see at what point the ID was first looked it.

My code below :

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT ID,
       Creation_Date,
       min(ACTION_DATE) as First_Action
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID;
QUIT;
```

This looks, from following some guides, that it should work. However the output I get looks like :

```
ID    Creation_Date       FIRST_ACTION
1     01JAN19:00:06:33    1830851902 
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    1830853260
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    1830853260
2     04JAN19:11:31:34    1830853260
3     21JAN19:09:17:01    1830854958
3     21JAN19:09:17:01    1830854958
```

So I suspect its an issue with how my query is reading the date format. Can anyone help? I am fairly new to SAS/PROC-SQL and have not dealt with date types before.

Comment: You need to attach a format to the new variable you have created.  Right now it is just displaying the datetime values as the raw number of seconds.

Comment: Why are your including CREATION_DATE in the output? It is not listed in your description of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Replace GROUP BY ID by GROUP BY ID, Creation_Date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,
       Creation_Date,
       min(ACTION_DATE) as First_Action
FROM TABLE1 main
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1 sub
    WHERE sub.Action_Date < main.Action_Date
    AND sub.ID = main.ID
)
QUIT;
```

It searches for the data record where no lower Action_Date exists. That is the lowest date. This should also group the ID's, so only one data record per ID is outputted.

Comment: some explanation of what the above code does would be helpful

Comment: No Problem, it searches for the data record where no lower Action_Date exists. That is the lowest date. This should also group the ID's, so only one data record per ID is outputted.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer by editing it, not to the comment section